# Using transform and scaling from center point

Tags: javascript, math, transformation

I have a canvas where by I draw my circle at an angle using the transform function.

But i also use scale and translate for camera zoom and position. The problem is the transform function is causing the scaling to be based on it's top left corner, and I cannot figure out how to fix this problem.

This is my code:

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,element.width,element.height);        
    ctx.save();      

    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0.01, 0.01, 0.3*scale, scale, element.height/2*0.7);      
    ctx.translate(0-(camera.x - element.width/2),0-(camera.y-element.height/2));      

    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0,0,obj[i].radius,0,Math.PI*2);  
        ctx.lineWidth = 4.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

If you zoom in and out you can see the problem where by it is not staying in the correct place, the camera is drifting and I need to correct for that: http://jsfiddle.net/ub97gdgj/

How do i fix this anchor point problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the transform function, the whole image could be moved to make the rotation point at the center of the image.

```
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0.01, 0.01, 0.3*scale, element.width/2, element.height/2);
```

The 5th and 6th params of the ctx.setTransform are used for translate function.

http://jsfiddle.net/ub97gdgj/2/

Comment: Can you show a JSFiddle as i added that line before the transform but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: But this has removed all functionality for camera position.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ub97gdgj/2/
The camera position is moved after the drawing completed.